# QGIS qgis2threejs color points and set radius expression

Tags: qgis, expression, qgis2threejs

I use Terrain from Google Maps, then I have an import list from csv with earthquake location, depth and magnitude.

As I'm not familiar with this tool I managed as much as I could with trying options but all my points of the earthquake are the same radius and same color.
I saw expression but I don't know how to use it to set point radius size by earthquake magnitude and point color by depth.
Can you advise on this?

Also is there a way to create something like a grid that shows depths and latitude and longitude in this view?